# Why are some airplane seats numbered "DEK"?

Tags: aircraft, seating

I'm in an Avianca Airbus A320 and the seats are numbered ABC, DEK. Any particular reason why not "DEF"?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I have never before noticed this, but a quick check over several airlines at [Seatguru](http://www.seatguru.com) confirmed that other airlines do that as well.

The logic behind this is that the letters A and K will always be window seats. The letter K is chosen, because it's the highest that you can go in a normal airplane with 10 seats across (An [A380](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Singapore_Air/Singapore_Air_Airbus_A380.php) for instance). I is omitted because of it's resemblance to 1.

Note that Avianca does this even for the smaller airplanes, where you'll have ACDK. B and E are omitted so that C and D are always aisle seats. This is also maintained on the bigger [A330](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Avianca/Avianca_Airbus_A330-200.php), where numbering is AC - DEFG - JK.

Just to illustrate, here's are the seat configuration for all their planes:

```
AC - DEFG - JK
AC     -    DK
ABC    -   DEK
```

So A and K are window seats; C, G seats with aisle on the right; D, J seats with aisle on the left; B,E,F middle seats.

It's a little illogical on the other side though, I don't understand why they use J instead of H, would make more sense to put a H, then if they happen to buy bigger air planes, they could just fit in the B and the H.

There's a little bit more information on this on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_seat_map#Seat_designation).

Comment: +1, I answered earlier, but this answer is much more explained.

Comment: A number of airlines also use similar numbering patterns front to back, as you will walk past rows 1 to 8 in upper class then the first economy row is 30.

Comment: @tom true, airlines I work for do that.

Comment: @Tom Damn. That's why a 30-something seat is always further forward than I expect!

Comment: Similarly, you'll often see "AC DEF" on a single-aisle narrow-body with 5 seats across — and the same plane might be "AC DF" in business class. (The US carriers I'm familiar with don't bother going up to J or K on a plane with only a single aisle).

Comment: I wonder if the reason for this is because in some of the software systems, there's a code that goes something like if row["K"] then do_blah() or similar is the reason for this illogical numbering

Comment: I would have assumed the JK series is so that people who are in seat J can tell that they are sitting next to the person in seat K, but then the DK and DEK series don't make any sense.

Comment: @LieRyan No, I think it's more for the sake of the passengers and ticket agents to be able to know from the seat number what type of seat it is without having to remember all of the different configurations. Also, when an equipment swap happens, they can keep most of the seat numbers the same and what was booked as an aisle seat doesn't suddenly become a middle seat.